# In ARM64 Assembly, output is only showing %d

Tags: function, output, addition, arm64

I'm new to assembly in general and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong in this code.

```
.text
.global _start
.align 2

_start:
    mov x0, #2                  // first number
    mov x1, #2                  // second number

    bl add_numbers
    bl _printf
    bl _terminate

_printf:
    mov x0, #1                  // stdout
    adr x1, result_string       // endereço da string de resultado
    mov x2, #30                 // string length
    mov x16, #4                 // sys_write
    svc 0                       // syscall
    ret

_terminate:
    mov x0, #0                  
    mov x16, #1            
    svc 0
    ret                  

add_numbers:
    add x0, x0, x1
    ret

result_string: .ascii "Result: %d\n"
```

as I understand it, the result should be 4, but this is:

```
Result: %d"
```

Comment: Your `_printf` function is not an actual `printf`. It just writes `result_string` to stdout exactly as-is.

Comment: @Michael how do I solve that? I tried other things but still don't working

Comment: @Christinne look at the source code of some open-source `printf` implementation.